# Prove that every real number is an eigenvalue of differentiation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

"Let G be a vector space of functions of class $C^\infty$ and

$ \varphi: G \ni f \mapsto f' \in G$

($\varphi$ is linear).

Prove that every real number is an eigenvalue of $\varphi$."

To be honest I don't really know where to start with this one, could anyone please give me some hints?

Comment: An eigenvector with some eigenvalue $\lambda$ would be a nonzero function $f$ with $f'=\lambda f$. Does this look familiar from calculus?

Comment: @Ian if $f'=\lambda f$, then e.g. $f = e^{\lambda x}$ and since I can construct such function for every real number $\lambda$, then every real number is an eigenvalue?

Comment: That's right. ${}{}$

Comment: By the way, for fun, do you know what the generalized eigenspace of the differentiation map for a given eigenvalue $\lambda$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for actually proving it, you could write something like first let $Df=\frac{df}{dx}$,and choose $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ then it is obvious that 
$$
De^{\lambda x}=\lambda e^{\lambda x}
$$
which holds for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and which satisifes $Df=\lambda f$ since
$$
\lambda e^{\lambda x}=\lambda f
$$
also note that $\lambda e^{\lambda x} \in C^{\infty}$ (you can use the Taylor series expansion of $e^{x}$ to prove that $e^{\lambda x}$ is analytic and hence smooth).

Also on a side note, that notation that is being used is horrifically convoluted. A much more clear way of writing this would be let $\varphi:C^{\infty} \to C^{\infty}$ such that

$$
\varphi f=\frac{df}{dx}
$$
I guess that is more a matter of taste but just my $0.02 on it.